# SQLite NOT LIKE not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working in SQLite with a large complex database. I am trying to create a query that will get me all breeding ewes i.e those that are not marked as Sell or Butcher.

I use a field called alert01 to contain data that I need to be aware of when I scan and look up a sheep. A sheep that is for sale will have Sell or Sell? in that field somewhere. A sheep that could go to butcher will have Butcher or Butcher? in that field. Some sheep have both in their alert text field because they could either go to slaughter or be sold.

This query will correctly find all adult ewes that are either for sale or for butcher that are present on the farm:

```
SELECT sheep_table.sheep_id, 
 sheep_table.sheep_name, sheep_table.birth_date, 
sire_table.sheep_name as sire_name, dam_table.sheep_name as dam_name , sheep_table.alert01
FROM sheep_table 
left join sheep_table as sire_table on sheep_table.sire_id = sire_table.sheep_id
left join sheep_table as dam_table on sheep_table.dam_id = dam_table.sheep_id
WHERE sheep_table.remove_date is ''
and sheep_table.sex = 2
and sheep_table.birth_date not like "2014%"
and (sheep_table.alert01  like '%Butcher%' or sheep_table.alert01  like '%Sell%')
order by  sheep_table.sheep_name asc
```

This one does not find the not for sale or butcher sheep and I don't understand why.

```
SELECT sheep_table.sheep_id, 
 sheep_table.sheep_name, sheep_table.birth_date, 
sire_table.sheep_name as sire_name, 
dam_table.sheep_name as dam_name, sheep_table.alert01
FROM sheep_table 
left join sheep_table as sire_table on sheep_table.sire_id = sire_table.sheep_id
left join sheep_table as dam_table on sheep_table.dam_id = dam_table.sheep_id
WHERE sheep_table.remove_date is ''
and sheep_table.sex = 2
and sheep_table.birth_date not like "2014%"
and (sheep_table.alert01 not like '%Butcher%' or sheep_table.alert01 not like '%Sell%')
order by  sheep_table.sheep_name asc
```

It gets almost all the sheep only eliminating those that have both Sell and Butcher in the alert01 field.

I am totally lost, to me the second query is just the complement of the first so I can't figure out why it's not working as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse the condition correctly, you have to apply [De Morgan's law's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
WHERE ... (alert01 NOT LIKE '%Butcher%' AND alert01 NOT LIKE '%Sell%') ...
                                        ^^^
```

Comment: Thank You! I was pretty sure I was doing something stupid <bangs head> Thanks so much!